# WSO2 ESB how to identify the request soap version

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I need to return the soapfault accoding to the request soap version (1.1 or 1.2). I use ESB 4.8. Is there a simple way to identify the soap version? Can be automated the proper custom response fault according to the request?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can filter the messages based on the namespace used for the versions.

SOAP 1.1 : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/

SOAP 1.2 : http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope

i.e:

```
<filter xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xpath="/soapenv:Envelope ">
```

With that configuration, you can filter and get SOAP 1.1 requests. More information can be find [here](http://wso2.com/library/articles/differentiating-between-soap-versions-looking-soap-message/)